# Converting the Hive SQL output to an array[Double]

Tags: apache-spark

I am reading some data from a hive table using a hive context in spark and the out put is a ROW with only one column. I need to convert this to an array of Double. I have tried all possible ways to do it myself with no success. Can somebody please help in this ?

```
val qRes = hiveContext.sql("""
            Select Sum(EQUnit) * Sum( Units)
            From pos_Tran_orc T
            INNER JOIN brand_filter B
            On t.mbbrandid = b.mbbrandid
            inner join store_filter s
            ON t.msstoreid = s.msstoreid
            Group By Transdate
            """)
```

What next ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply map using `Row.getDouble` method:

```
qRes.map(_.getDouble(0)).collect()
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the file location as a variable in saveAsTextFile ? ss_data.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("<variable>")..Thanks